# New computer, good specs, OS hangs occasionally even though CPU usage is <10% and RAM usage is < 30%

Tags: windows-7, freeze

So here's my build:

- **CPU** – AMD FX-8350 4.0GHz 8-Core Processor
- **Motherboard** – MSI 970A-G46 ATX AM3+ Motherboard
- **Memory** – Crucial Ballistix Sport 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1600 Memory
- **Storage** – Mushkin Chronos 120GB 2.5" Solid State Disk
- **Video Card** – Sapphire Radeon HD 7870 GHz Edition 2GB Video Card
- **Case** – NZXT Source 210 (Black) ATX Mid Tower Case
- **Power Supply** – Rosewill Hive 650W 80 PLUS Bronze Certified ATX12V / EPS12V Power Supply
- **Optical Drive** – Asus DRW-24B1ST/BLK/B/AS DVD/CD Writer

My OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

For some reason, the computer will hang almost every time I open a new webpage in Chrome, and sometimes it just hangs for seemingly no reason. By hang, I mean that the OS is unresponsive for a short period of time (usually 5-10 seconds) before I can click something again. I can move the mouse while this happens.

Here's a picture of the temperatures... I don't know if this is normal or not:

[image]

Comment: This normally indicates a bad HDD.  I would inline your picture but the "Add Picture" opens up a new window of the question instead of generating a link to be inlined.

Comment: Bah, I just got this SSD in yesterday... is there a diagnostic tool I can run on it?

Comment: I saw SSD on @Seiyria build

Comment: @Seiyria - You having a SDD is important information ( I don't go to random websites ). Have you updated the firmware?  I am under the firm believe a question should have all the generic information in the question itself.

Comment: if not hardware problem, it can be OS or program running on OS problem. Like infected by virus, antivirus scan process, anything

Comment: @Hardy - Its a brand new installation.  Its very likely its not an infection.

Comment: @Ramhound It still freezes from time to time, but I think I figured out why: I'm downloading Guild Wars 2 onto the SSD. I tried browsing for a while with and without the installer. Since it downloads all the files individually, I think it might be the number of I/O operations that is causing this lag. What do you think?

Comment: An SSD is the one item which should handle IOps very well. (Assuming AHCI is enabled. It might do weird things with high queue depths and ancient IDE legacy mode selected).

Comment: @Hennes well, I guess I'm not sure then. When these lag spikes start occurring, the installer goes from a 6MB/s download down to 0b/s download, and it has to be restarted before it will even continue.

Comment: I've looked into this and from other Superuser questions I've found that Sandforce SSDs are a problem, so I think that may be it. I'm not sure though.

Comment: The installer sounds like its a streaming download.  Have you updated the firmware?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I have updated it. It appears to be a little better, but I'm chalking that up to placebo for the time being.

Comment: @Seiyria - Unlikely a placebo.  I assume TRIM support is enabled?

Comment: @Ramhound No, it isn't. I'll work on enabling that now.

Comment: @Seiyria - The problems you face are common configuration problems with SSD.  While a SSD is fast, because of its limited size ( and how it handles writes in the first place ) if you don't tell it to clean up after itself it will think its at its usage capacity.  That is basically what TRIM is, marks unused filled cells as free so they can be overwritten.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the bit of info. I've enabled TRIM and so far (knock on wood) everything seems to be flowing a lot better.

Comment: @Seiyria - Oh and the long waits is the SSD trying to find room for the files.

Comment: I don't have anything to add outside of what @Ramhound is saying, but I do want to menthion that I have experienced the same thing in the past with my corsair SSD and Windows 7 x64. Had no such issues under Windows 7 x86. The freezes & loooong bootups come and go in spurts, but it's usually a tweak to my Radeon through CCC that gets it back in check. Not sure if it's related.

Comment: @Ramhound if you want to make an answer, I can accept it for you. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was just what you were doing at the time of the screenshot, but it looks like your CPU(s) are being eaten up by a process.  I would launch task manager to find out what is taking all the cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on my system once also here is what I did:

1. Turn off Windows 10 Dynamic ticking. I don't know what exactly it is but it's about DPC. And for my case I have to disable it.

Run Command Prompt as Administrator, type the commands below:

bcdedit /set disabledynamictick yes

bcdedit /set useplatformclock no

Type bcdedit again to check the status.

2. It's also related to the Windows 10 network components. Need to optimize the network for Windows 10 for reducing the DPC lantency.

http://www.speedguide.net/downloads.php

Just download the TCP Optimizer and use the "optimal option"
After doing these above, restart your system.